# Android - Parse Content /Information from .ICS File into String

Tags: android, string, parsing, listview, icalendar

is it possible to read .ICS Calender Files and to extract Information / Data from them, without extracting the content into the android Calender class. 
I want to parse parts of the content of the .ICS file into a String variable.

For example:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20140331T080000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20140331T114000
X-WWS-ID:3
UID:3-1-1395841927-calendar--klasse12@dsgenf.w-da.net
CREATED:20140326T135207Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20140326T135245Z
DTSTAMP:20140326T135245Z
X-WWS-C_USER_ID:128849019103
X-WWS-M_USER_ID:128849019103
SUMMARY:Englisch-Klassenarbeit
SEQUENCE:2
END:VEVENT
```

From this Event in the .ICS I want to extract the DTSTART and SUMMARY and put them in a String variable, which I then can display in a ListView.

Any Help is Appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: Off course. It is just a text file. You are lucky.. nothing as simple as parsing wanted info out. What's actually your problem?

Comment: OK cool, I not sure where to start. I ve heard about XML parsing and JSON parsing but nothing really describes how to simply do this filtering of a ics or text file.

Comment: Inspect every line for the wanted variable name.

Comment: ok thanks, can you give me a quick example please ?

Comment: Did you google for reading file line by line?

Comment: Yes, that shows me to how to read a file in general, but I was wondering how to filter out just specific words. For example I only want to get the line in which "UID: " is written.

Comment: Well post your code for reading a file line by line. After that we can help you by checking if the line has the content you want.